# Change UI without recompiling in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to write an application as calculator with Xamarin.forms.
Instead of using XAML I use code behind to create the user interface.

I want to save the UI settings in external folder. When I want to change the UI, I just need to change that file without recompiling.
(something like button's text, button's color ...)

Is that possible? It would be great if I could do it even with excel file ^^

Any help is really appreciated... Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, Could you share some code to explain this "I want to save the UI settings in external folder. "? It will be helpful to understand what your means.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - I haven't found the best way yet. I think I want to do something like this.
btnNumber1.Text = WorkBook.Sheet("A1").Content;
btnNumber1.Color= WorkBook.Sheet("A1").Color;

Each time you open the application, it will load data from the excel file. When I want to make changes, I just make changes in the excel file.

Comment: @Jason - Can you show me more? I am newbie in Xamarin. i haven't experience. ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't work this one out yet, you can either implement a local database and fetch/update from there, implement [themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming)

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I want. But it looks helpful. Thanks